# While applying or deriving electric field and potential relation why is the field considered constant?

Tags: electrostatics, electric-fields, potential

The relation is :
  $$\text dV = -\mathbf E\cdot \text d\mathbf R$$ (both of $E$ and $\text d\mathbf R$ are vectors ) .
I have seen some questions and derivations where it is assumed constant. Please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: In various classical cases $E$ is not constant. For example, when we calculate the potential in the space around a point-like particle or a spherical charged particle. I would say, $E$ is constant only when there are flat plates or distributions of charges. Maybe you refer to the direction of $E$. Please clarify, or put a link to an example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is true in general. You can start with the definition of potential energy of the electrostatic force (or really any conservative force in general).
$$\mathbf F=-\nabla U$$
And then divide both sides by the charge exerting the field in question:
$$\frac{\mathbf F}q=-\nabla \left(\frac Uq\right)$$

The value on the right is just the electric field, while the value on the left is the negative gradient of the electric potential
$$\mathbf E=-\nabla V$$

Or, using the fundamental theorem of calculus:
$$V(\mathbf b)-V(\mathbf a)=\Delta V=\int_C\nabla V\cdot \text d\mathbf r=-\int_C\mathbf E\cdot\text d\mathbf r$$
where we have done a line integral along some path $C$ from some position $\mathbf r = \mathbf a$ to another position $\mathbf r = \mathbf b$

If we make $\mathbf a$ and $\mathbf b$ infinitesimally close so that $\mathbf b=\mathbf a+\text d\mathbf r$ then
$$V(\mathbf a+\text d\mathbf r)-V(\mathbf a)=\text dV=-\mathbf E\cdot\text d\mathbf r$$

Notice how we didn't assume anything about a constant electric field. **This is true for any electric field**

However things work out nicely if the field is constant in space, since
$$\Delta V=-\int_C\mathbf E\cdot\text d\mathbf r=-\mathbf E\cdot\int_C\text d\mathbf r=-\mathbf E\cdot\Delta\mathbf r$$
and you no longer have to perform a line integral.

So comparing what we have, in general:
$$\text dV=-\mathbf E\cdot\text d\mathbf r$$
and for constant electric field:
$$\Delta V=-\mathbf E\cdot\Delta\mathbf r$$
which shows the power of calculus very nicely: on the infinitesimal scale we can essentially treat our functions as constant.

Answer (score 0):

In order to *derive* the equation you quote, **E** might just as well be constant. That is because, over the small displacement, d**R**, that you are considering, a reasonably well-behaved **E** will not change significantly.

The equation then follows from the definition of *work*, since **E** is force per unit charge (one a test charge) and d*V* is the work done per unit charge (on a test charge). The negative sign arises because if force and displacement are in the same direction, the charge will lose electrical potential energy.